# how to embed an youtube video on my html page?

Tags: html, youtube, embedded-video

I want to include a few youtube link on my webpage...Can anyone help me with this? I am relly new to this and i have no idea about the formats or things like these....Could you explain me what should I use and how to embed it between my html code?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

Just:

1. Visit video's page
2. Click the Share button
3. Click the Embed button
4. Copy/paste the code

Some videos are set to not be embeddable.

Answer (score 2):

Try googling for "embed youtube video html". There's only 11.6 Million results, but you should be able to find something there.

- [YouTube on Your Site](http://www.youtube.com/youtubeonyoursite)

Answer (score 0):

Just below the video in the youtube page there is a button named "Share".

Clicking that will expand the sharing box. Just click share and you will get an iframe which you can just copy and paste in your websites html.

Answer (score 0):

you may find these [youtube search results](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how%20to%20embed%20a%20youtube%20video%20into%20a%20website&oq=how%20to%20em&aq=9&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=95l4001l0l11797l8l8l2l0l0l0l392l1450l0.3.1.2l6l0) helpful