# How To Add Youtube Video On A Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am still pretty new to web developing and i am trying to create a new website for fun and just to test my skills so forget me if i m asking alot from this platform.

but i wanna add a youtube video to my webpage and i can't find anything on stack overflow regarding this but can anyone show me a platform where i can copy/paste the code or someone provide me with it again sorry if asking a lot i have tried github,stack overflow and tried finding on google but everything is related to something else  :( any help would be apreciated thank you in advance

Comment: Just using 3 keywords from your title turns up many, many duplicates, eg in addition to the first I linked, there is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964928/how-to-embed-an-youtube-video-on-my-html-page), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034648/how-to-put-youtube-video-on-the-same-site), maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556087/html-trying-to-embed-youtube-video).  If your searching did find these or others, you need to let us know that you've found and tried them, and describe why they didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the video on your page using `<iframe>`. [You can find instructions here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en).

The embed code can easily be found by clicking share button on any YouTube video.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HTML5, the best way to achieve this is by using the `<iframe>` tag.
Here is an example (you'll find some stupid dolls jumping and moving):

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"></iframe>
```

`autoplay=1` will make the video playing when the page is loaded:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY?autoplay=1"></iframe>
```

But there are two deprecated tags in HTML, I don't recommend to use them.
They are `<object>` and `<embed>`.
An example of using `<object>`:

```
<object data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"></object>
```

Another example if using `<embed>`:

```
<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
```